# How to create dynamic array of hashes in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I am doing POST request to the endpoint using HTTparty gem in Ruby on Rails application.

I am passing request body as json in the POST request.

```
request_body = {}
request_body[:name] = "John"
request_body[:age] = 26
request_body[:revenue] = [{id: "price"}, {id: "tax"}}]
request_body[:contact] = [{id: "email"}, {id: "phone"}}]
```

I am creating the above request body structure for multiple request. 
How can I form the request body in a better way?

Is there a way to create array of hashes by passing only the values(e.g. price and tax) instead of using like below

```
request_body[:revenue] = [{id: "price"}, {id: "tax"}}]
```

Below is my scenario, I want to pass the values of hashes and method will return array of hashes.

**Input**:

```
attributes = %w(price tax)

array_of_hashes(attributes)
```

**Expected output:**

```
def array_of_hashes()
 [{id: "price"}, {id: "tax"}}]
end
```

Comment: can you post an example of your requirement, do you want to create an array of hashes wih the keys you specify

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty Refer my update. I want to form the array of hashes in a dynamic way

Comment: From what input?

Comment: @NickM Refer my question. I have already updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
def array_of_hashes array
   array.map{ |el| {id: el} }
end
```

and

```
array_of_hashes(["price", "tax"]) -> returns [{ id: "price" }, {id: "tax"}]
```